# Cannot get away from the "Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object global] is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've read all the post that treat the same problem of mine without success.

I create a script to load a page fragment with jQuery that works fine in a test page where just the jQuery reference is on.
At the time I embed the code in a wordpress theme, that use the same jQuery version, everything stops working.

I get different results accordingly the position where my script reference is embedded.

- If code is at the very end of the page, it doesn't work, possibly due
  to the effect of the .noConflict(); called somewhere else.
- Re-instating the object $ with a $ = jQuery.noConflict(); doesn't
  work; I don't get error in the console, but the code doesn't work as
  expected.
- Having the script reference loading before the jQuery reference
  produce the error as in the title.

I'm really puzzled about the results I'm getting and I was wondering if somebody can explain where I'm getting this wrong.

Comment: Can u supply the code here or in a jsfiddle for is to see any errors

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress automatically calls `jQuery.noConflict()` just after embedding jQuery, so it doesn't conflict with other frameworks using `$`. What it actually means is that using jQuery by `$` isn't possible anymore.

There are two possible solutions:

1. Use `jQuery` instead of `$`, for example like this:

   ```
   jQuery(function() {
       jQuery('a').click(function() {
           // ... more code ...
           // Just replace all $s with jQuery
       });
   });
   ```
2. Use an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) to locally re-enable `$`:

   ```
   (function($) {
       // All your code goes here, $ will work as usual
   })(jQuery);
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer gronostaj

In the end I have been able to use the $ without IIFE, but I have to reframe the location of the <script> inclusion.